# form crashes when I dont select an item in a combobox

Tags: c#, combobox, itext

so I have a form with some textboxes and comboboxes, in the code I use the textbox.text and combobox.selecteditem.tostring() to write into a pdf file using iTextSharp, like

```
Paragraph p = new Paragraph("\n" + "Code: " + textBox1.Text + "\n" + "Gender: " + comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString());
doc.Add(p);
```

so when I leave a textbox empty, it works fine
but when I leave a combobox without selecting an item, the form gives unhandeled exception and crashes

I tried using this code but it didn't help

```
foreach(ComboBox ncb in this.Controls.OfType<ComboBox>())
                {
                    if(ncb.SelectedItem == null)
                    {
                        ncb.SelectedItem = "";
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Side note: you can take advantage of [interpolated strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx). Your first line becomes `Paragraph p = new Paragraph($"\nCode: {textBox1.Text}\nGender: {comboBox1.SelectedItem}");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get an exception since `comboBox1.SelectedItem` is null, and `comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString()` causes NullReferenceException..

You can handle it easily by removing `.ToString()`

```
Paragraph p = new Paragraph("\n" + "Code: " + 
                             textBox1.Text + "\n" + 
                             "Gender: " + comboBox1.SelectedItem);
```

An example how it would work:

```
object o = null;
string s = "aaa" + o + "bbb";
```

s would be `aaabbb`

Answer (score 0):

If all you're interested in is the string value of the combobox, why not just use the `.Text` property?

```
Paragraph p = new Paragraph($"\nCode: {textBox1.Text}\nGender: {comboBox1.Text}");
```